# Intergrating MediaWiki and FOS UserBundle

Tags: symfony, mediawiki, fosuserbundle

I am looking at adding a wiki to my Symfony2 website. After a bit of research, MediaWiki looks to be my best bet.

Has anyone written a plugin to allow the FOS Userbundle to process the Auth on the MediaWiki side?

I have noticed I can write my own, but I am not sure how to do that on the controller side. If no one has written a plugin, how to I link the MediaWiki Auth Extention and the FOS Entity? I am quite happy with a list of links for this one.

Comment: You may want to share your experience in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Requests_for_comment/AuthManager so that such a job is made easier in the future.

Comment: We actually decided on LDAP and hooked into MediaWiki and Redmine that way.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check list of hooks available at MediaWiki, like [UserLoadFromSession](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/UserLoadFromSession)
It will allow to trigger your current authentication system.

IMHO, you have three types of integration:

1. Try to configure some [plugin](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/AuthPlugin)
2. Create UserListener in your project, which will create session/cookies for mediaWiki
3. Trigger symfony project authentication from some hooks in mediaWiki(There are a lot of them)